# What is the difference between preparing encrypted partitions and then installing whereas using the installer to enable encryption

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, encryption

I had recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 (single boot) on a new laptop but my workplace requires full disk encryption on all employee laptops so I am thinking about re-installing Ubuntu (single boot) with encryption enabled

I saw two tutorials on how to perform a full disk encryption with Ubuntu 20.04:

1. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRSElRlp7TQ) instructs to open the terminal do some partitioning and some other stuff and then start the installation
2. [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIvZVr6P4fc) timestamp 2:52 where the person selects the Erase and install option and goes to advanced features and enables encryption

The second one seems easier and quicker so I wanted to know what is the difference between the two. What I want to achieve is to have a single boot installation of Ubuntu 20.04 with full disk encryption (I am assuming that this means all the directories are encrypted except for `/boot`) and I am ok with data being overwritten

Since I never had to worry about partitions while installing Ubuntu I was thinking about going with option 2

UPDATE:
So I tried option 2 but turns out it doesn't fully encrypt the system so I am gonna go with 1

Comment: Option 1 is if you want full control over everything and know exactly what you're doing. In option 2 Ubuntu does most of the stuff under the hood without any option to change it, e.g. use of LVM or which partitions are used for /, /home etc. Option 2 is probably your best choice if you're not already well experienced in Linux or have a strong case for a particular setup not supported by the installer.

Comment: but will option 2 encrypt the directories other than my home like `/etc` and `/usr` thats my main concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend following [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019).

You will end up with **encrypted /boot/** and root file-system which is considered almost Full Disk Encryption (FDE).

Comment: yeah just found that one, was following it, thanks

Comment: And _why_ do you recommend that?

Comment: And why wouldn't I? OP asks about a way to achieve full disk encryption and I refer to an excellent and straightforward tutorial which is a part of the community help wiki. OP says thanks. And there you are downvoting me, I guess that made your day a bit more pleasent.